# PHP not getting files uploaded via FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple different pages on my website that allow users to upload files to the server. These are uploaded via JQuery AJAX using FormData to a php file that then processes them and saves them. Here's an example of the ajax being used:

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

In upload.php, I have code that checks if the file `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` exists, then uses `move_uploaded_file()` to save it. This has been working perfectly for quite some time, but all of a sudden, I come in today and all file uploads across the site are just not working. When I try `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_FILES)` in upload.php, they are both just empty arrays, meaning the post request is not actually sending the form data?

I have tried this in both FireFox and Chrome and the result is the same. Also, I don't have access to the apache configs, `but phpinfo()` shows that I have `file_uploads: On`, `max_file_uploads: 20`, `upload_max_filesize: 512M` (which is much larger than the file I am trying to upload), and `upload_temp_dir: no value`. I am wondering if maybe this `upload_temp_dir` is what could be causing the problem, but I don't know if that's what it was set to before.

Any ideas why this might not be working?

EDIT: Here's a picture of my chrome developer tools showing the 'payload' of the request.
[image: payload]

Comment: Is your console.log showing anything?

Comment: check your Developers Tools - Network tab, are any of your fields sent in the request ? any errors in your console ?

Comment: @Adam - When I log `$('#fileToUpload')[0].files[0]`, it shows the file. However, seems like the php page isn't getting any info from the POST.
@darklightcode - Just edited the post with a picture of the 'payload'